# Avro schema resolution for evolving a field from a primitive to a union

Tags: java, avro

I'm working with Avro 1.7.0 using the its [Java's generic representation API](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/index.html) and I have a problem dealing with our current case of schema evolution. The scenario we're dealing with here is making a primitive-type field optional by changing the field to be a union of `null` and that primitive type.

I'm going to use a simple example. Basically, our schemas are:

- Initial: A record with one field of type `int`
- Second version: Same record, same field name but the type is now a union of `null` and `int`

According to the [schema resolution chapter](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Schema+Resolution) of Avro's spec, the resolution for such a case should be:

> **if reader's is a union, but writer's is not**
>   The first schema in the reader's union that matches the writer's schema is recursively resolved against it. If none match, an error is signalled.

My interpretation is that we should resolve data serialized with the initial schema properly as `int` is part of the union in the reader's schema.

However, when running a test of reading back a record serialized with version 1 using the version 2, I get

**`org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Attempt to process a int when a union was expected.`**

Here's a test that shows exactly this:

```
@Test
public void testReadingUnionFromValueWrittenAsPrimitive() throws Exception {
    Schema writerSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse("{\n" +
            "    \"type\":\"record\",\n" +
            "    \"name\":\"NeighborComparisons\",\n" +
            "    \"fields\": [\n" +
            "      {\"name\": \"test\",\n" +
            "      \"type\": \"int\" }]} ");

    Schema readersSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(" {\n" +
            "    \"type\":\"record\",\n" +
            "    \"name\":\"NeighborComparisons\",\n" +
            "    \"fields\": [ {\n" +
            "      \"name\": \"test\",\n" +
            "      \"type\": [\"null\", \"int\"],\n" +
            "      \"default\": null } ]  }");

    // Writing a record using the initial schema with the 
    // test field defined as an int
    GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(writerSchema);
    record.put("test", Integer.valueOf(10));        
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JsonEncoder jsonEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().
       jsonEncoder(writerSchema, output);
    GenericDatumWriter<GenericData.Record> writer = new 
       GenericDatumWriter<GenericData.Record>(writerSchema);
    writer.write(record, jsonEncoder);
    jsonEncoder.flush();
    output.flush();

    System.out.println(output.toString());

    // We try reading it back using the second schema 
    // version where the test field is defined as a union of null and int
    JsonDecoder jsonDecoder = DecoderFactory.get().
        jsonDecoder(readersSchema, output.toString());
    GenericDatumReader<GenericData.Record> reader =
            new GenericDatumReader<GenericData.Record>(writerSchema, 
                readersSchema);
    GenericData.Record read = reader.read(null, jsonDecoder);

    // We should be able to assert that the value is 10 but it
    // fails on reading the record before getting here
    assertEquals(10, read.get("test"));
}
```

I would like to either know if my expectations are correct (this should resolve successfully right?) or where I'm not using avro properly to handle such a scenario.

Answer (score 6):

The expectations that migrating a primitive schema to a union of null and a primitive are correct.

The problem with the code above is with how the decoder is created. The decoder needs the writer's schema rather than the reader's schema.

Rather than doing this:

```
JsonDecoder jsonDecoder = DecoderFactory.get().
    jsonDecoder(readersSchema, output.toString());
```

It should be like this:

```
JsonDecoder jsonDecoder = DecoderFactory.get().
    jsonDecoder(writerSchema, output.toString());
```

Credits goes to Doug Cutting for the answer on avro's user mailing list:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/avro-user/201208.mbox/browser

Comment: The exact comment is here: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/avro-user/201208.mbox/%3CCALEq1Z-%2Bsaq1No7M%3DkADE4SfwpLFjx3bfm-mYdoaa-rHz8Z1RQ%40mail.gmail.com%3E